# How to prevent a login from 'listing' a table or view definition in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, security, authentication, authorization

Is there a way to prevent a login from listing the tables and columns in a schema?

I have to give access to a remote login to query on a single view; however, I also must make sure that such login cannot list every object on that schema.

Is there something like MS SQL SERVER's `DENY VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO public;` on PostgreSQL?

Comment: Apparently can not be done. Reading https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-grant.html#SQL-GRANT-DESCRIPTION-OBJECTS I deduce than if for example you use two schemas you cannot do it also. "Without this permission, it is still possible to see the object names, e.g. by querying the system tables"

Comment: Ideally, row-level security would apply to system catalogs, so you could set rules about who can see what. But so far that's not supported.

Comment: The simplest answer to this, given that you want to DENY a VIEW from your question, is to create your tables in one schema and views in another schema and GRANT USAGE to the VIEW schema and GRANT SELECT on the VIEWs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) to the rescue:

> `UPDATE`
>
> [...]
>
> For schemas, allows access to objects contained in the specified schema (assuming that the objects' own privilege requirements are also met). Essentially this allows the grantee to "look up" objects within the schema. Without this permission, it is still possible to see the object names, e.g. by querying the system tables. Also, after revoking this permission, existing backends might have statements that have previously performed this lookup, so this is not a completely secure way to prevent object access.

This means, the following would satisfy your requirements, unless `alice` tries hard enough:

```
CREATE SCHEMA invisible; -- no privileges granted on this schema to alice or public

CREATE VIEW invisible.iamnothere AS SELECT 'something not very interesting'::text AS data;

GRANT SELECT ON TABLE invisible.iamnothere TO alice;
```

Now `alice` will see the following (using `psql`, and hopefully it is the same in other clients, too):

```
SELECT * FROM invisible.iamnothere;
              data              
────────────────────────────────
 something not very interesting

\dt invisible.*
No matching relations found.
```

### If you are serious

...about preventing your user from seeing other objects, it will be slightly more complicated.  You have to handle the notice in the docs about system tables access.

First, do

```
REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA  pg_catalog FROM public, alice;
```

This, as it suggests, can be disruptive to anyone who is able to browse the schemas through implicitly being a member of `public` (all roles are members of the latter).  To restore the status quo for them (but not `alice`), you can do:

```
CREATE ROLE object_browser;

GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA pg_catalog TO object_browser;

GRANT object_browser TO bob;
```

After this, `bob` will be able to list stuff, while poor `alice` is confined to querying that single view.

Comment: Probably we with Alice have different conceptions of "hard" :)

Comment: @Abelisto :D  In my practice, even experienced devs are sometimes without ideas when it comes to databases.  Now I added a stricter solution, which is not so easy to circumvent - unless a colleague next to Alice can list the objects.  Also, don't hesitate to add the solution using an FDW.

Comment: ¡Warning! Is not hard to a user accidentaly view the pg_class data. For example if you connect the database with ODBC. @dezso If you are serious section's  is mandatory!

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
I think I will use another database with FDW.

PD: We really don't like Alice :D

Comment: `iamnothere` is a view, not table, so if alice runs `\dv invisible.*` instead of `\dt invisible.*`, she will see it in the list.

Comment: @ChrisKobrzak After running looking into the above again, I see that the `REVOKE` prevents `alice` from listing the view: `test=# \c - alice [...] test=> \dv invisible.
ERROR:  permission denied for relation pg_class`

Comment: `alice` can still list other schemas if using DBeaver or PgAdmin GUI.